# Vuex state returns no response on page reload

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a Vuex Authentication that stores the state of signed-in user data. It works okay during sign in but if I reload the page after signing in the mutation payload returns no data because for some reason the axios request URI changes, it removes the `/api` after reloading the page not sure why.

Comment: Please, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your case. If you don't know why your code that you've written removes /api, other users don't have any idea because they never saw it.

Comment: I was actually about to edit my post but I already fixed the problem. I forgot to dispatch the get user data request. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must save a token sent from the server to do this
To do this, when the server sends you a token, you must save it in the `localstorage` in your browser.
like this code in `mutations` method:

```
login(state, payload) {
    axios({
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/login',
        data: payload
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.data.token) {
            state.user_token = response.data.token;
            localStorage.setItem('user_token', state.user_token)
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
console.log(error)
    });
}
```